# What is underlying representation of `long` data type in Python (or CPython)?

Tags: python, long-integer, cpython

As stated in [5.4. Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex): `Long integers have unlimited precision.`

If the implementation of `Python` is `CPython`, then what can be the underlying representation for the `long` type? For sure, it cannot be either `int` or `long long int` in `C/C++`.